# ng-view not loading partial view into index.cshtml

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am learning angularjs and working on a single page application using the ng-view. Unfortunately, my partial views won't load into my index.cshtml. Instead they load as a separate page. Below is my code:

```
            <html>
            <head>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
                <title>Index</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div ng-app="employeeInfoApp" ng-controller="employeeCtl">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <!--Example of a Dropdown List-->
                        <select ng-model="employeeinfo.EmpName" ng-options="employeeinfo.EmpName for employeeinfo in EmployeeInfoes">
                            <option value="">-- Please Select A Client Company --</option>
                        </select>
                        <p></p>
                        <!-- Example of Table of Data-->
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Emp Name</th>
                                    <th>Dept Name</th>
                                    <th>Designation</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr data-ng-repeat="emp in EmployeeInfoes">
                                    <td>{{emp.EmpName}}</td>
                                    <td>{{emp.DeptName}}</td>
                                    <td>{{emp.Designation}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <p></p>
                        <a href="addemp">Add Employee</a>
                        <div ng-view class="container"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </body>
            </html>

            <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
            <script src="~/Scripts/angular-resource.js"></script>
            <script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
            <script src="~/Scripts/LegalScripts/legalServices.js"></script>

            <script>

                //Name the module
                var app = angular.module('employeeInfoApp', ['ngResource', 'legalServices', 'ngRoute']);

                app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.
                        when('/addemp', {
                            templateUrl: 'AddEmp.cshtml',
                            controller: 'EmployeeInfoController'         
                        }).
                        otherwise({
                            redirectTo: '/home'
                        });
                    }]);

                //Add the controller
                app.controller("employeeCtl", ["$scope", "EmployeeInfo", function ($scope, EmployeeInfo) {

                    $scope.EmployeeInfoes = EmployeeInfo.query();

                    $scope.SelectedEmployeeInfo = {};

                }]);


            </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't load `.cshtml` file directly from its path you need to load it from MVC controller action as it contains razor which which should be parsed using MVC Razor view engine likewise suppose you had `Employee` controller that will contain an action `AddEmp` that will return a view indirectly using `c#`

**App.js**

```
  $routeProvider.
  when('/addemp', {
        templateUrl: 'Employee/AddEmp', //you need to call controller action
        controller: 'EmployeeInfoController'         
  }).
```

Comment: Trying that still resulted in the partial view popping up in a separate page.
Here is what my controller looks like:

    `public ActionResult Index()`
    {
     return View();
    }

    public ActionResult AddEmp()
    {
     return PartialView("AddEmp");
    }

Comment: @JimShelley it shouldn't be return a partial instead it should be `public ActionResult AddEmp() { return View("AddEmp"); }` & inside your `AddEmp.cshtml` view you should define `@{Layout = null}`

Comment: Still not working. Here's my partial view: @{
    Layout = null;
}

This is the partial view

Comment: Why you don't added any content in it?? and which controller it belongs too??

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that I was using Angular 1.4 (which visual studio nuget package manager automatically installs.)

Routing in Angular 1.4 has been changed to accommodate using multiple views (and components) but the old ng-view directive won't work. See this Introduction to Routing in 1.4

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/891436/Introduction-to-Basics-of-Angular-newRouter

My quick fix solution was to download the Angular 1.3 scripts library into my project. Then my partial views worked fine.