# ng-view not loading partial view into index.cshtml 2

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

In relation to 
[ng-view not loading partial view into index.cshtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30652955/ng-view-not-loading-partial-view-into-index-cshtml) the first answer says use version 1.3 to get ng-view to work on a PartialView is this still the case? What is the latest version I can use. I tried 1.3.18 should I keep trying earlier versions?

For my code base refer to http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1054/single-page-spa-crud-application-aspnet-mvc-angularjs